# How do I get the same result with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Coming from intermediate python background, I just started learning javascript and I find it hard to figure out what's wrong with my code. I got the expected result with python but not with javascript.

**The question**

Write a program that uses console.log to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print "Buzz" instead.

When you have that working, modify your program to print "FizzBuzz", for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print "Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those).

**Code in python**

```
for x in range(100):
    if x % 3 == (x % 5) == 0:
        print('FuzzBazz')
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print('Fizz')
        continue
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print('Buzz')
        continue
    print(x)
```

**Code in JS**

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 3 === x % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  }
  if (x % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
    continue;
  }
  if (x % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
    continue;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 mistakes, both in the same line:

1. You forgot a `0` after your first comparison `x%3`
2. You forgot to include the AND operator `&&` in the line

Therefore

`if(x%3===x%5===0)`

should actually be:

`if(x%3===0 && x%5===0)`

Also, worth pointing out that `else` can be used instead of `continue`, like so:

```
if (x%3===0 && x%5===0) {
    console.log("fizzbuzz");
} else if (x%3===0) {
    console.log("fizz");
} else if (x%5===0) {
    console.log("buzz");
} else {
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Maybe also mention that he's used `continue;` in his JS, which isn't valid

Comment: Actually @Lissy I just looked it up and I think it is valid. Still, I would argue that `continue` is redundant in OP's case since execution will continue regardless.

Comment: `continue` is not redundant, as it skip the *rest* of the loop; however, it is not the only way of accomplishing the goal either: `else if`s should be used instead of subsequent `if`s and an `else` should be added at the end to print the original number if none of the other conditions match

Comment: According to the problem the code is right, the only mistake is the condition.

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas This code still outputs the number on Fizz and Buzz

Comment: Look at this _and still print "Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those_

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas "...print "Fizz" *instead of the number*..."

Answer (score 1):

The 2 mistakes are

1. you have used `if(x%3===x%5===0)` which is wrong because x%3===x%5 is true not 0 and this will be compared to 0 which will always be false so modify it to `(x%3===0 && x%5===0)`.
2. since both multiples of 3 and 5  should be replaces with FizzBuzz it shd be in a if else loop other wise for `eg : 15 it will print FIZZBUZZ and FIZZ and BUZZ which is wrong.`

I have modified the code please have a look at it.

```
for (var x=0; x<100; x++){
if(x%3===0 && x%5===0){
  console.log("FizzBuzz");
}else{
  if(x%3===0){
  console.log("Fizz"); 
  }if(x%5===0){
    console.log("Buzz");
  }
  console.log(x);
 }
}
```

Comment: 2 is incorrect. `continue` will ensure it skips the other branches

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
for (var x=0; x<10; x++){
if(x%3===0 && x%5===0){
  console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
if(x%3===0){
  console.log("Fizz"); continue;
}
if(x%5===0){
  console.log("Buzz");continue;
}
 console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes from the fact that JavaScript handles comparisons slightly differently to Python.

When you run `x%3===x%5===0`, you're expecting JS to compare `x%5` to `0` and `x%3` to `x%5` as Python does. However, JS compares `x%3` to `x%5`, which results in either `true` or `false`, which it then compares to `0`. Because neither `true` or `false` are equal to `0`, that expression will always evaluate to `false`.

Your comparison expression directly translated to JS would look like `x%3 == 0 && x%5 == 0`. However, as `15` is the lowest common multiple of `3` and `5`, that expression is identical to `x % 15 == 0`.

There has also been some discussion in comments and other answers as to whether `continue` is necessary or even legal in JS. The answer to both is "yes, it is", however there is a simpler method.

Rather than using continue, as in the following code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 15 == 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
    continue;
  }
  if (x % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
    continue;
  }
  if (x % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
    continue;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

it is possible to use `else if` as in this code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  if (x % 15 == 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (x % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
  } else {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

This final piece of code is how I would implement fizzbuzz in JavaScript.